# SMS printer integration in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is any one familiar with smsprinter integration in codeigniter. My orders should send to the sms printer.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a broad question... It will be completely dependent on the printer bought and it's API/driver and if it will work on windows or linux or both, or if it's serial, usb, ip-based etc. Each printer should have it's own way to communicate.

Will need MUCH more information to even guess at an answer!!!